# Kivy - How to get contents of TextInput

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I don't know how to get information from a text entry box. Other questions were not helpful, so I hope someone can help me in my specific case. I am using Kivy v.1.11.1 and Python 3.7.

Here's my code:

*user.py*

```
"""User-end software for signup/account data."""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class LoginScreen(Widget):
    """Class for login screen contents."""

    pass  # Python code for TextInput boxes should go here, I think.


class UserApp(App):
    """Main app."""

    def build(self):
        """Build app."""
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UserApp().run()
```

*user.kv*

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<LoginScreen>:
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top + 20
        text: "Offbox Insurance"
    Label:
        font_size: 64
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 30
        text: "Log in"

    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 140
        text: "Email"
    TextInput:
        id: email_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 216
        multiline: False

    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 240
        text: "Password"
    TextInput:
        id: password_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 316
        multiline: False

    Button:
        font_size: 20
        height: 50
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 380
        text: "Log in"

    Label:
        font_size: 16
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 75
        text: "Don't have an account?"
    Button:
        font_size: 16
        height: 36
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 5
        text: "Sign up"
```

I need both of the TextInputs to be stored in their own variables so I can handle them separately.

Comment: When do you want to get the texts of the TextInputs? When is the button pressed?

Comment: I'm expecting the user to enter a username and password then click a login button. I need to be able to evaluate the contents of those two text boxes, and either A) Move on to the next menu, or B) Show text telling the user that the information is incorrect.

Comment: try with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextInput texts can be mapped through a StringProperty. Also assuming that you want to get that information when any of the buttons is pressed then you must call a function using on_press.

```py
"""User-end software for signup/account data."""
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class LoginScreen(Widget):
    """Class for login screen contents."""

    email = StringProperty()
    password = StringProperty()

    def login(self):
        print("email:", self.email, "password:", self.password)


class UserApp(App):
    """Main app."""

    def build(self):
        """Build app."""
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    UserApp().run()
```

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<LoginScreen>:
    email: email_input.text
    password: password_input.text
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top + 20
        text: "Offbox Insurance"
    Label:
        font_size: 64
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 30
        text: "Log in"
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 140
        text: "Email"
    TextInput:
        id: email_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 216
        multiline: False
    Label:
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 240
        text: "Password"
    TextInput:
        id: password_input
        font_size: 24
        height: 40
        width: root.width * 5 / 7
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 316
        multiline: False
        password: True
    Button:
        font_size: 20
        height: 50
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.top - 380
        text: "Log in"
        on_press: root.login()
    Label:
        font_size: 16
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 75
        text: "Don't have an account?"
    Button:
        font_size: 16
        height: 36
        center_x: root.width / 2
        top: root.height / 12 + 5
        text: "Sign up"
```